# css animations, animation-name, smoothstate.js

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, css-transitions, css-animations

Trying to animate some page transitions with [smoothstate.js](http://weblinc.github.io/jquery.smoothState.js/index.html), and I'm at an impasse.

Here's a jsfiddle, but it's throwing a console error that I'm not getting when developing. However you can still see the css issue i'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/3f5wp9xL/6/

Here's another demo, that doesn't have the console error:  http://davidwesleymartin.com/animtest/index.html

All animations are set in CSS (via @keyframe, animation properties).

The animations work on page load, but are behaving strangely when I try to reverse them after a link is clicked. I am trying to reverse them by resetting the 'animation-direction' property when an exit class ('is-exiting') is added to the main container after a link is clicked.

The only way I can get this to work is by also setting a NEW value for 'animation-name', if this is the same value as it was before, it doesn't work.

Relevant HTML:

```
<div id='main'>
  <aside class='main-side'>
    <div class='anim_element anim_element--fadeIn'>
      <h2>sidebar</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='index.html'>Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='index.html'>Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='index.html'>Link 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <div class='main-content'>
    <div class='anim_element anim_element--fadeInLeft'>
      <h1>Main Content</h1>
      <p>Lorem...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS (**note**:everything is properly prefixed on the demo, that is not the issue):

```
@keyframes fadeIn{
    0% {
        opacity:0;
        transform:scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {opacity:1;}
}
@keyframes fadeInLeft{
    0% {
        opacity:0;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}

#main .anim_element{
    animation-duration: .25s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

#main .anim_element--fadeIn{
    animation-name: fadeIn;
}
#main .anim_element--fadeInLeft{
    animation-name: fadeInLeft;
}

#main.is-exiting .anim_element{
    animation-name: fadeIn; 
    animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}
```

Comment: Can you please put the demo code in a jsfiddle, embedded in the question itself, or something similar? It'd make helping you a bit earlier

Comment: Alright I added a demo on jsfiddle

Comment: fixed. that's what I get for drunken jsfiddling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me.

http://davidwesleymartin.com/animtest/index.html

But jsfiddle demo is broken. I think you need to specify the page to load in `href`.

It works.

```
<a href='index.html'>Link 3</a>
```

It doesn't work.

```
<a href='/'>Link 3</a>
```

The point is the linked page has `#main` element or not. I think this is kinda bug of smoothState.js. The error occurred in this line for me that is when finding a `#id` element.

https://github.com/weblinc/jquery.smoothState.js/blob/master/jquery.smoothState.js#L215

**UPDATE**

To restart css3 animation, you need to redraw element.

more info: http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

```
;(function($) {
  'use strict';
  $.fn.restartCSSAnimation = function(cls) {
    var self = this;
    self.removeClass(cls);
    $.smoothStateUtility.redraw(self);
    setTimeout(function () { self.addClass(cls) });
    return self;
  };
  var $body = $('html, body'),
      content = $('#main').smoothState({
        // Runs when a link has been activated
        onStart: {
          duration: 1000, // Duration of our animation
          render: function (url, $container) {
            // toggleAnimationClass() is a public method
            content.toggleAnimationClass('is-exiting');
            // restart animation
            $('.anim_element--fadeIn').restartCSSAnimation('anim_element--fadeIn');
            $('.anim_element--fadeInLeft').restartCSSAnimation('anim_element--fadeInLeft');
            // Scroll user to the top
            $body.animate({scrollTop: 0});
          }
        }
      }).data('smoothState');
})(jQuery);
```

CSS

```
#main .anim_element--fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
          animation-name: fadeIn; }

#main .anim_element--fadeInLeft {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
          animation-name: fadeInLeft; }

#main.is-exiting .anim_element {
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
          animation-direction: alternate-reverse; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jewmmqoa/2/

Comment: Sorry, my question might not have been clear. There are 2 stages to the animation:

1. When page loads (sidebar scales up, main content comes in from left)

2. When a link is clicked (elements are supposed to reverse their entrance animation). 

(2) is what isn't working properly. Following the demo at:  http://weblinc.github.io/jquery.smoothState.js/typical-implementation.html It should happen just by changing the animation-direction property when 'is-exiting' is applied to the main div. This does not happen, unless I declare a new animation which is DIFFERENT from the original.

Comment: Thus the main-content animates off, but the sidebar does not. (i.e. the "animation-name" value applied on exit is new for the main-content part, but not for the sidebar.

Comment: it works! Many thanks to you, good sir. That was driving me crazy.